# Jedi Project and Delphi 11 doesn't install via GetIt

Tags: delphi, jedi

I have attempted to install Jedi into Delphi 11, it goes through the installation process and Getit reports it as installed but it does not appear in the component palette.  I have Jedi installed in Delphi 10.4.

Both JEDIVisualComponentLibrary and JEDICodeLibrary (Both JCL-2021.09) have been copied to the CatalogRepository but looking in the Options\language\Delphi\library none of the JediVCL libraries were entered and and only the 32 bit version of the CodeLibrary.

I entered the paths in Options/Language/Delphi/Library and restarted Delphi but none of the Jedi VCL controls appeared on the Palette.

Tried running uninstall from GetIt but nothing seems to happen then it says Done. Where do I find the actual Install/Unistall programs?

How do I clear out the Jedi Libraries and what is the best way to install them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got into your same situation and I didn't find JVCLInstall.exe either.

I went into folder:

```
..\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\CatalogRepository\JEDIVisualComponentLibraryJVCL-2021.09\install\JVCLInstall
```

and opened JVCLInstall.dproj in Delphi 11 IDE. I run it from there and a JVCL install wizard poped up. I went through it and, despite some warnings, I got the components installed and available after closing and opening the IDE.

Comment: Thanks, yes I stumbled through to the same process.  Should have answered my own question and closed the question.

Comment: I found I also had to checkmark "New installation / Upgrade from an older version". It seemed the GetIt installation only installed JEDI for 64-bit Windows, and forgot 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Getit in Alexandria doesnt show any of the jcl jvcl links at all.  It was so easy to install in the Sydney version.