# Class TJvBalloonHint not found, even though JEDI Code Library is installed

Tags: delphi

I have been asked to take over a Delphi project, and am having trouble setting up the dependencies. The previous developer told me I needed to install the JEDI Code Library, which I did via the GetIt Package Manager...

[image]

However, when I try to open the project in Delphi 10.4 Community Edition, I get an error "*Class TJvBalloonHint not found*".

A quick search reveals that the `TJvBalloonHint` class is part of the JEDI library (see [this page for details](https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JVCL_Help:TJvBalloonHint)), so I'm not sure why it's not loading.

Anyone able to advise? Thanks

**UPDATE** Just came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69827865/jedi-project-and-delphi-11-doesnt-install-via-getit?rq=1). However, if I look in `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\21.0\CatalogRepository` I don't have a folder for JEDI at all, even thought GetIt shows it as installed. Not sure if this is relevant, but thought I'd better add it in case.

**UPDATE 2** Following the comment by @edbored, I installed the visual component library as well, but it didn't help...

[image]

Comment: You need both the JCL and the JVCL (JEDI Visual Component Library) - also in Getit

Comment: @edbored Thanks for the tip. I installed both, but still get the same error. Please see my updated questions

Comment: The JEDI JVCL is built into multiple packages. Apparently, the one containing that component isn't being loaded. Use the Components->Install Packages menu to see which JVCL component packages are being loaded, and load the ones that aren't that you will need. The package descriptions all start with *JVCL*. The TJVBalloonHint is in the *JVCL Custom Controls* package.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why aren't you asking the developer who told you that you need to install it for help doing so?

Comment: @KenWhite I looked in the Install Packages, but can't see anything relating to either JEDI or JVCL in the list. I tried searching for the custom controls package, but nothing came up. As for the previous dev, he's no longer on the project and isn't very forthcoming about this, which is why I'm struggling with it.

Comment: @KenWhite Also, I started a new Delphi project and looked in the palette. Can't see this control in there, and searching the palette for "jv" doesn't show anything, implying that these two packages aren't actually installed. However, even after restarting Delphi, GetIt shows them as installed and Install Packages doesn't list them at all. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry, one more comment. I found this [thread](https://community.embarcadero.com/pt/forum/tools/9873-getit-cannot-will-not-uninstall-jedi), which describes exactly my situation (I didn't restart Delphi in between), but I don't understand the answer. No idea which uninstaller he means, nor where to find `clean.bat`. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Ah, saw a post somewhere else that suggested deleting the registry entries for jedi and deleting the component library folders in my own user's catalog (didn't realise it stored them there as well as in the public user's documents folder). After that, when I installed, it all went fine. I got the jedi install wizard, which I never saw before. All sorted now, thanks for the help